# Extra symbols in URL with ngRoute prevent loading the right view

Tags: angularjs, redirect, ngroute

I am new to AngularJS although we're on Angular now but in my company we're still on this version. Anyway now I am using ngRoute and I am faction a problem. When I click a button that must load another page from the partials it adds some extra symbols in the URL bar on my browser.
Here is my code :
app.js

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('craApp', ['consultants-directive','ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/index.html'})
        .when('/consultants', {templateUrl: 'partials/clts.html'}, function () {
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    }]);

})();
```

my index.html page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr"  ng-app="craApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Tecos - Appication de gestion de CRA</title>
        <script src="resources/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="consultants.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/angular-route.js"></script>

        <base href="/">
    </head>
    <body >
        <!-- Fixed navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
          <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Tecos CRA</a>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Saisie d'activité<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Administration</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#/consultants">Gérer les consultants</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Gérer les projets</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Gérer les demandes de congés</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Recherche ...">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Recherche</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Fixed navbar -->

        <!-- Main content -->
        <div ng-view>

        </div>
        <!--<consultants-bloc></consultants-bloc> -->
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click `<a class="dropdown-item" href="#/consultants">Gérer les consultants</a>` I get this in the URL bar:

> http://127.0.0.1:9090/#%2Fconsultants

Comment: If you're using HTML5 mode, it should be `href="consultants"`

Comment: Problem not solved ! It redirects me to a non existent page `consultants.html`

Comment: You'll need to find out what's doing that. Nothing in your question should take you to `consultants.html`

Comment: when I removed the `#` from `href="#/consultants"`as you told me it does that